# LogOut button only if logged in in front end menu widget

Tags: logout

I would like to add a "LogOut" button at the end of my sidemenu - but of course only, if someone is logged in. I also want to have it in two languages using qtranslate.

At the moment I have created a new Menu Item "Log Out" with a link to `/wp-login.php?action=logout` which works, but always shows up of course.

Is there a way to put something like this in the function? Any help - or just a hint would be very nice! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a menu item to the end of a nav menu [you can use the `wp_nav_menu_items` hook](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.2/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php#L228). Combine that with [`is_user_logged_in()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in) and you ought to have it.

```
function add_last_nav_item($items) {
  if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
    return $items .= 'your login link';
  }
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items','add_last_nav_item');
```

As far as translation, I assume that qTranslate uses the [standard translation functions](http://codex.wordpress.org/L10n), but I'm not sure as I don't use it and as it is a third party plugin that part of the puzzle is off-topic anyway.

Comment: Thanks! This works great. But how could I tell, that it is only shown in a menu widget called e.g.: shop menu? thanks!

Comment: I can't quite tell what you are asking but it is going to depend on the widget most likely. Do you have that code?